# TYPO3 frontend: cObj not available, enableFields not usable

Tags: typo3

The server logs of my TYPO3 7.6.2 installation contain the following error:

> Call to a member function enableFields() on string in .../File.php on line 23

and the relevant code is:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObj->enableFields('table');
```

I cannot reproduce this error myself, but apparently it's happening now and then.

`cObj`'s default value in `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController` is the empty string, which means that it has not been initialized yet - but `Http\RequestHandler` initializes it with `->newCObj()` as far as I see.

---

Under which circumstances can it happen that `cObj` is not initialized in TYPO3 frontend requests?

Answer (score 2):

Some Extensions will initialize `TypoScriptFrontendController` on there own, and perhaps ignore this call.

That is often the case for older extensions dealing with AJAX Requests.
Same goes for Backend / Command Line actions that need some kind of functionality only available with initialized `TypoScriptFrontendController`.

You can check installed extensions whether they try to initialize the class themselves and are missing the call.

Inside of the log you probably have a referrer to get even more information where the issue occurs.